# Why are my divs breaking, and why isn't my bounce effect working?

Tags: jquery, css, html

For a class, we're designing a website (can be found here: http://web.cs.dal.ca/~webucat/) and I'm playing around with it a bit.

As the website's supposed to be geared toward children, I wanted to make it a little more interactive and fun, and make the top tab buttons bounce when they're clicked. I'm running into some trouble with doing this, however.

For one, in my HTML I added divs for all the links, so I could access the buttons with jQuery for the bounce effect, but when I did it broke my CSS it seems. (See: all pages except the contact page, where I removed the divs.)

Here's the navigational tabs HTML:

```
<div id = "links">
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href = "index.html" class="tab">Home</a></div>
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href ="math.html" class="tab">Learn Math</a></div>
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href ="geography.html" class="tab">Learn Geography</a></div>
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href ="spelling.html" class="tab">Learn Spelling</a></div>
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href ="music.html" class="tab">Learn Music</a></div>
    <div class="bounce-tab"><a href ="contact.html" class="tab">Contact Teacher</a></div>
</div>
```

Also, my jQuery appears not to be working for the button bounce. I've searched around, and I thought I implemented the code correctly (heck, I even ran it on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gzWb3/ and it works), and I even looked around on StackOverflow but it seems I'm doing it right for the most part, but just something small isn't working, but after mulling over the code I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add bounce effect to the navigational tabs that active on click
    $(".bounce-tab").click(function () {
        $(this).effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
    });
});
```

And here's my referencing to it in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So basically, could someone lend me some help in making our CSS work again, and have the buttons bounce? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take out the line where you load jQuery 1.3. It wouldn't hurt to update jQuery UI either-- they're on 1.8.17 now.

Comment: Note that the example page CRASHED my browser. I don't know what you've done, because it takes some doing to crash a browser without it hanging for a long time first...

Comment: I would suggest you use a <UL>, unordered list, for your links, since this what your ad-hoc div structure is trying to be; Plus, it will be more friendly too screen readers for the disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and jQuery UI must load before your scripts.js since your code is dependent on both.

Loading an extra version of jQuery ( 1.3) just adds more issues....only load jQuery once

Answer (score 1):

`div`'s are block level elements meaning they stack on top of each other.

on your contact page you have one div with all your links in it.

instead of wrapping in `div`'s wrap in `span`'s as they will run in-line from left to right by default.

eg.

`<span class="bounce-tab"><a href = "index.html" class="tab">Home</a></span>`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzWb3/1/)

Comment: I tried this, and even left your example code up, and it won't work. http://web.cs.dal.ca/~webucat/index.html

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 1 of scripts.js`, you need to include jQuery before you can make jQuery calls like $(document).ready()

I'd also strongly recommend downloading firebug for FireFox or using the debugging console on Google Chrome, they both tell you exactly what's wrong

Comment: How am I not including jQuery?

Comment: You are, but browsers read your webpage from top to bottom, it first loads up your `scripts.js` it doesn't know what to do with `$(document).ready()` as you haven't loaded jQuery at this point in time, then it loads jQuery. Load jQuery BEFORE loading your `scripts.js`

Comment: Okay, I did that now, and it's visibly making progress, but it's still not working properly. http://web.cs.dal.ca/~webucat/